# I cant figure out why I am getting [WinError 10057] error

Tags: python, sockets, server

I am using the socket module to create a server, And I was just testing my network file, And it seemed to be working, After I made updates to the client file and server file, I try to run the network file again to see if everything's alright, and I get this error
[WinError 10057]
I can't figure out why am I getting this, Please help, Here is my code

```
import socket

class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = "my ip"
        self.port = 5555
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
        self.pos = self.connect()
        print(self.pos)

    def getPos(self):
        return self.pos

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except:
            pass

    def send(self, data):
        try:
            self.client.send(str.encode(data))
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = Network()
    print(n.send("Hello, Working! :)"))
```

This is the output

```
None
[WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
None
```

Comment: Please paste in the real error you're getting, with traceback, not just "this error [WinError 10057]"

Comment: Welp, I edited the output just now, Can you please refresh your webpage?

Comment: Get rid of those `try: except:` blocks – you're losing the traceback doing that.

Comment: Um, In which line? There are multiple try: except: blocks in my code

Comment: All of them. You're mishandling errors by just throwing them away.

Comment: Okay, I am doing that rn

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\DEBARKA NASKAR\Desktop\Chess\network.py", line 27, in <module>
    n = Network()
  File "c:\Users\DEBARKA NASKAR\Desktop\Chess\network.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
AttributeError: 'Network' object has no attribute 'server'

Comment: There you go - now you have your actual error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242900/discussion-between-debarka-naskar-and-akx).

Comment: Please join the chat, I really need help

Comment: The exception you now have is _impossible_ with the code you have included in your post (since `self.server` definitely is defined before that line). Please edit in your actual code into the post.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\DEBARKA NASKAR\Desktop\Chess\network.py", line 27, in <module>
    n = Network()
  File "c:\Users\DEBARKA NASKAR\Desktop\Chess\network.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.pos = self.connect()
  File "c:\Users\DEBARKA NASKAR\Desktop\Chess\network.py", line 17, in connect
    self.client.connect(self.addr)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused 
it

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo when trying something

Answer (score 0):

Never, *ever* do `try: ... except: ... pass` unless you absolutely, positively know what you're doing.

1. Just `except:` is practically never alright; it will also swallow `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt`, which will make your program hard to interrupt or exit. Instead, to catch all exceptions, `except Exception:`.
2. Secondly, don't just wrap a full function in a `try: ... except ...: pass`. Unless you really do mean that "well whatever happened this function, if it went wrong, I don't care, yolo". (You don't mean that.)

Then, your real exception, from the comment:

```
File "c:\Users\DEBARKA NASKAR\Desktop\Chess\network.py", line 27, in <module>
  n = Network()
File "c:\Users\DEBARKA NASKAR\Desktop\Chess\network.py", line 9, in init
  self.pos = self.connect()
File "c:\Users\DEBARKA NASKAR\Desktop\Chess\network.py", line 17, in connect
  self.client.connect(self.addr)

ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

There is no server process listening on the host and port you've specified (but with your prior code you could have never known since you just swallowed the error and yolo-ed forward).

You will need a server process, too.

Comment: So what changes should I make to my code? I am new to this module, so I don't know much

Comment: Changing the code you now have won't help you with anything, if you don't have a server process to connect to. Please read up on how client/server sockets work, e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#

Comment: How can I have a server process to connect to?

Comment: @DebarkaNaskar Please _read the article_ I just linked above. It starts off by telling you just that in the section "Creating a socket".